# Help for a property of complete measure space

Tags: integration, measure-theory

i hope you can help me. It is just a  little question about an exercice.
Here is the exercice :

Let $(\Omega, A, \mu)$ a measure space and $(\Omega_0, A_0, \mu_0)$ its completion. 
Show that for every $A_0$-elementary function $u$ there are $A$-elementary function $u_1,u_2$ such that :

(i) $u_1 \leq u \leq u_2$

(ii) $\mu(\{u_1 \ not \ equal \ u_2  \}) = 0$.

To find it i said that we can write $u$ in that way :

$u := 1_{[N^c}]u_1 + 1_{[N}]u'$  or $u := 1_{[N^c}]u_2 - 1_{[N}]u'$ where $u'$ is an elementary function in $A_0$ and $N$ is the union of all $\mu$-null subsets from $\Omega$. 
If i can write $u$ like that the conclusion is easy to show.

Do you think that is correct ? The problem for me is the minus in the second definition.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, that your method does not work. If $N$ is the union of all $\mu$-null subsets then it might well be that $N=\Omega$. This is the case if for every $\omega\in\Omega$ we can find a $\mu$-null set that contains $\omega$ as element.

---

Start with  an $\mathcal{A}_{0}$-elementary function $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$
that satisfies $u\left(\Omega\right)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$.

Then we can write $u=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}n\mathbf{1}_{A_{n}}$ where the
$A_{n}$ are disjoint elements of $\mathcal{A}_{0}$ with $\Omega=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}A_{n}$.

Then sets $B_{n},C_{n}\in\mathcal{A}$ exist with $B_{n}\subseteq A_{n}\subseteq C_{n}$
and $\mu\left(B_{n}-C_{n}\right)=0$.

Then the functions $u_{1}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}n\mathbf{1}_{B_{n}}$
and $u_{2}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}n\mathbf{1}_{C_{n}}$ are $\mathcal{A}$-elementary
with $u_{1}\leq u\leq u_{2}$.

If $u_{1}\left(\omega\right)<u_{2}\left(\omega\right)$ then for some
$n$ we must have $\omega\in B_{n}-C_{n}$ so that $$\mu\left(\left\{ u_{1}<u_{2}\right\} \right)\leq\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mu\left(B_{n}-C_{n}\right)=0$$

This can be done also if we start with $u\left(\Omega\right)\subseteq\frac{1}{k}\mathbb{Z}=\left\{ \frac{n}{k}\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\} $
for any positive integer $k$.

Keeping this in mind we now focus on the general case.

If $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is an $\mathcal{A}_{0}$-elementary function
then so are the functions $u^{\left(k\right)}=k\lfloor\frac{1}{k}u\rfloor$
for positive integers $k=1,2,\dots$ and for such functions $u^{\left(k\right)}$
above we proved that $\mathcal{A}$-elementary functions $u_{1}^{\left(k\right)},u_{2}^{\left(k\right)}$
exist that satisfy $u_{1}^{\left(k\right)}\leq u^{\left(k\right)}\leq u_{2}^{\left(k\right)}$
and $\mu\left(\left\{ u_{1}^{\left(k\right)}<u_{2}^{\left(k\right)}\right\} \right)=0$.

Observe that $u=\lim_{k\to\infty}u^{\left(k\right)}$ and define $u_{1}:=\limsup_{k\to\infty}u_{1}^{\left(k\right)}$
and $u_{2}:=\liminf_{k\to\infty}u_{2}^{\left(k\right)}$.

Then $u_{1}$
and $u_{2}$ are $\mathcal{A}$-elementary functions with $u_{1}\leq u\leq u_{2}$.

If $\limsup_{k\to\infty}u_{1}^{\left(k\right)}\left(\omega\right)<\liminf_{k\to\infty}u_{2}^{\left(k\right)}\left(\omega\right)$
then some $k$ must exist with $u_{1}^{\left(k\right)}\left(\omega\right)<u_{2}^{\left(k\right)}\left(\omega\right)$
so $\left\{ u_{1}<u_{2}\right\} \subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}\left\{ u_{1}^{\left(k\right)}<u_{2}^{\left(k\right)}\right\} $
and consequently $\mu\left(\left\{ u_{1}<u_{2}\right\} \right)=0$.

Comment: Waw i am really impressed. I was a student in physics and i must do measure theory because i want to study statistics. But as i can see, i have a lack of knowledge. Thank you for yours answer.

Comment: Glad to help. And good luck with your study in statistics.

Comment: Can you explain me how you go from the second line to the third ? You said "Then we can write... " . 
I do not see the implication

Comment: Define $A_n:=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid u(\omega)=n\}$. Now take some fixed $\omega_0\in\Omega$ and let $n_0=u(\omega_0)$ or equivalently $\omega_0\in A_{n_0}$. If you substitute this $\omega_0$ in the function $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} n\mathbf 1_{A_n}$ then again the outcome is $n_0$. This because $\omega_0\in A_{n_0}$ and for every $n\neq n_0$ we have $\omega_0\notin A_n$. So both sides $u$ and  $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}n\mathbf 1_{A_n}$ give the same outcome if $\omega_0$ is substituted. This works for every $\omega_0\in\Omega$ so we conclude that the functions are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I well understand that part of the proof but Sorry i made a mistake. I didn't understand the existence of the sets $C_n$ and $B_n$. Can you explain me please ?

Comment: The existence of $C_n,B_n\in\mathcal A$ with $B_n\subseteq A_n\subseteq C_n$ and $\mu(C_n-B_n)$ is a direct consequence of the fact that $(\Omega,\mathcal A_0,\mu_0)$ is the **completion** of $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$. A set $A$ will belong to $\mathcal A_0$ if and only if sets $B,C\in\mathcal A$ exist with $B\subseteq A\subseteq C$ and $\mu(C-B)=0$.